# React Native Fetch Request Fails Without CSRF Token

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, react-native, fetch, csrf

I've been developing a mobile complement to my web application built with Rails. Using Fetch API, I keep getting the notice "Can't verify CSRF token authenticity".

```
export const login = (user) => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/session', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({user})
  })
  // promise handling
}
```

**Edit:** Managed to get it to work but I still don't really understand why. If anyone has the same problem, this is how I resolved it. I managed to get the form_authenticity_token from my rails application and saved it as a variable that I then passed to the function. Haven't tested removing the credentials key.

```
export const login = (user, token) => {
  return fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/session', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ user, authenticity_token: token })
  })
```

Comment: Did you have to make any changes in your session controller to get this to work? I'm having a similar issue but this fix isn't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add **CSRF** token in headers or disable / remove **CSRF** on cross domain request.

```
export const login = (user) => {
  fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/session', {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': token
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({user})
  })
  // promise handling
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately did not solve the problem.

Comment: Where do you get token?

Comment: Here is another script that you can follow [Retrieving csrf token from a django app with react native](https://gist.github.com/jqn/e6a2073e26f5db90a55664f53a1fcbad)

Answer (score 0):

When working with Django backend you should set:

```
'X-CSRFToken': csrf_token  // not 'X-CSRF-Token' !!!
```

in your JS request headers.

**Environment:**
To set the token on the backend side, use:

```
{% csrf_token %}  <!-- put this in your html template -->
```

And then, to get the token in the JS code:

```
const csrf_token = document.getElementsByName('csrfmiddlewaretoken')[0].value;
```